# Hashtags in workflow email message

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, email, sharepoint-email, hashtags

I have a SPD workflow that sends an email to specific users when a list item has changed.  One of the items to display in the email is the category for the item. (Category: [%Current Item:Category%]) with the "Lookup For String" settings set at:

- Data Source: Current Item
- Field from Source:  Category
- Return field as: As String (this is grayed out so I am unable to edit)

The email works as expected initially but with each change to the list item, a ";#" is appended to the category in the email -

- 1st change - Category
- 2nd change - Category;#
- 3rd change - Category;#;#
- 4th change - Category;#;#;#
- and so on

What can I do to make this stop?  I have seen suggestions to change the "Return Field As" dropdown to text but it does not allow me to change this field as it is grayed out.

Thank you and please advise.

Comment: Whats the data type of "Category" column ??

Comment: it is a dropdown - so choice

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan does the fact that it is a "choice" column help with troubleshooting?

Comment: is there anyone with a recommendation?

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan it is a choice from a lookup field